# AVFoundation + GC on Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, avfoundation, avurlasset, core-media

Anybody having trouble using AVFoundation with GC ON???

What I am experiencing is that when accessing the tracks property of an asset, the file stays open by Core Media. Why is this an issue, well because after a long while and opening up many other media files eventually AVFoundation will report too many open files.

I have tried everything, using Instruments to debug, weak references, @autoreleasepool you name it. In the end this is a bug within Core Media with GC.

So I guess the ultimate question is this:

An app with GC ON, is there a way to run some section of code asynchronously without GC?

Please someone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I am answering my own question.

Basically in short GC is dead!

Yep, the way to go is ARC. So for all those out there coding Mac OS X, use ARC versus GC.

Comment: See bottom of this link: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html